# How to block non-domain users from using Tomcat web app in WindowsServer2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat

As the title says, I want to block all users which are not in domain from using the Java web application. Here is how the structure in my case:

I have a hardware IPSec Site-to-site VPN from client to the server. At the client side everyone who will be connected to the router will get access to the VPN, which means they can see our network, and I don't have much chance to control it.

I have Tomcat with Java web app running on port 8080 using Windows Server 2008 R2. So, everyone who is connected to the hardware VPN, if they are in our domain or not, can get access to the web based app. I don't want this. I want to give access only to those who is in our domain. Tomcat is running on a domain joined server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IPSec domain isolation policy, which essentially says that all intra-domain communication must be encrypted from node to node with IPSec. There is, of course, a large configuration overhead to this, but it will accomplish exactly what you want - the server will reject all traffic from non-domain-joined computers that are not leveraging your domain-based IPSec policy.

Comment: but I already do have a hardware VPN connection.. do u mean I need to create a second IPSec?, the software one? I dont have any IPSec VPN in the WindowsServer, it's all hardware..

Comment: I'm not talking about another VPN. I'm talking about computer-to-computer communication encryption with IPSec. Read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163159.aspx

Comment: the chapters look amazing and seems just what i want. will get back later, see what will happen.

Comment: well, unfortunately.. It does work for a short time, but whenever i reboot the client I can't get access to the server anymore.. When I do connect it first time its fine, after the clients restart the firewall changes to public, and doesn't recognize domain anymore.. any ideas?\

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue. IPSec domain isolation is used quite a bit.